# Timerank command is not working without any errors

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

Why is my command not running?

I have a command (~timerank @user) for my discord bot. The bot should give the user a role.. But the command is not running. I dont get any errors while compiling. I registered my command like all other commands:

```
public class CommandManager {

    public ConcurrentHashMap<String, ServerCommand> commands;
    public CommandManager() {

        this.commands = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        this.commands.put("clear", new ClearCommand());
        this.commands.put("preview", new PreviewCommand());
        this.commands.put("client", new ClientInfoCommand());
        this.commands.put("help", new HelpCommand());
        this.commands.put("vote", new VoteCommand());
        this.commands.put("play", new PlayCommand());
        this.commands.put("stop", new StopCommand());
        this.commands.put("trackinfo", new TrackInfoCommand());
        this.commands.put("shuffle", new ShuffleCommand());
        this.commands.put("statchannel", new StatChannelCommand());
        this.commands.put("timerank", new TimeRankCommand());
    }

    public boolean perform(String command, Member m, TextChannel channel, Message message, MessageReceivedEvent event) {

        ServerCommand cmd;

        if((cmd = this.commands.get(command.toLowerCase())) != null) {
            cmd.performCommand(m, channel, message, event);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is my command:

```
public class TimeRankCommand implements ServerCommand {

    @Override
    public void performCommand(Member m, TextChannel channel, Message message, MessageReceivedEvent event) {

        //~timerank @User
        if (m.hasPermission(Permission.ADMINISTRATOR)) {
            List<Member> members = message.getMentionedMembers();

            if(members.size() >= 1) {
                for(Member memb : members) {

                    Guild guild = channel.getGuild();
                    Role role = guild.getRoleById(648047607486087168l);

                    if(memb.getRoles().contains(role)) {

                        guild.addRoleToMember(memb, role).queue();

                        LiteSQL.onUpdate("INSERT INTO timeranks(userid, guildid) VALUES(" + memb.getIdLong() + ", " + guild.getIdLong() + ")");

                        EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();
                        builder.setTitle("Timerank");
                        builder.setThumbnail("http://i.epvpimg.com/toDBaab.png");
                        builder.setFooter("Powered by Backxtar.");
                        builder.setTimestamp(OffsetDateTime.now());
                        builder.setColor(0xf22613);
                        builder.setDescription(memb.getAsMention() + " is **MUTED** for 15 minutes!");
                        channel.sendMessage(builder.build()).queue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my SQLManager:

```
public class SQLManager {

    public static void onCreate() {

        //TimeRank
        LiteSQL.onUpdate("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS timeranks(id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, userid INTEGER, guildid INTEGER, time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)");
    }

}
```

Anyone knows why the command is not running? If its a SQL problem i would get at least the message in the function..

Btw this is my function to remove the role after 15 min. (The function is always called after 1 min.):

```
public void onCheckTimeRanks() {
        ResultSet set = LiteSQL.onQuery("SELECT userid, guildid FROM timeranks WHERE ((julianday(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - julianday(time)) * 1000) >= 15");

        try {
            while(set.next()) {
                long userid = set.getLong("userid");
                long guildid = set.getLong("guildid");

                Guild guild = this.shardMan.getGuildById(guildid);
                guild.removeRoleFromMember(guild.getMemberById(userid), guild.getRoleById(648047607486087168l)).complete();

                LiteSQL.onUpdate("DELETE FROM timeranks WHERE userid = " + userid);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. I believe your code from the if statement should be `if(!memb.getRoles().contains(role)) {` instead of `if(memb.getRoles().contains(role)) {`, since it seems you want to search for users *without* the muted role. (That's what it seems your command is doing) Currently, your command is searching only for users that do have the role.
2. I'm not familiar with how SQLite stores timestamps, but if it works the same way that every other system stores timestamps(which it probably does), then you instead want to do `"SELECT userid, guildid FROM timeranks WHERE ((julianday(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - julianday(time)) /1000 /60) >= 15"` instead of `"SELECT userid, guildid FROM timeranks WHERE ((julianday(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) - julianday(time)) * 1000) >= 15"`. This will make it activate only for users where the time is greater than 15 minutes, instead of greater than 0.015 milliseconds.